# F# out parameters and value types

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

The following f# function works great if I pass references to objects, but will not accept structs, or primitives:

```
let TryGetFromSession (entryType:EntryType, key, [<Out>]  outValue: 'T byref) =
    match HttpContext.Current.Session.[entryType.ToString + key] with 
             | null -> outValue <- null; false
             | result -> outValue <- result :?> 'T; true
```

If I try to call this from C# with:

```
bool result = false;
TryGetFromSession(TheOneCache.EntryType.SQL,key,out result)
```

I get `The Type bool must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter`    Is there a way to have  the F# function handle both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the `null` value in `outValue <- null` restricts the type `'T` to be a reference type. If it has `null` as a valid value, it cannot be a value type!

You can fix that by using `Unchecked.defaultOf<'T>` instead. This is the same as `default(T)` in C# and it returns either `null` (for reference types) or the empty/zero value for value types.

```
let TryGetFromSession (entryType:EntryType, key, [<Out>]  outValue: 'T byref) =
    match HttpContext.Current.Session.[entryType.ToString() + key] with 
    | null -> outValue <- Unchecked.defaultof<'T>; false
    | result -> outValue <- result :?> 'T; true
```

Comment: Thank you, still getting used to type inference!

Answer (score 0):

I still think this is not "pretty"/idomatic F# code and would probably do some more seremonial with the following:

```
let myCast<'T> o = 
 match box o with
 | :? 'T as r -> Some(r)
 | _ -> None


let GetFromSession<'T> entryType key = 
 match HttpContext.Current.Session.[entryType.ToString + key] with 
 | null -> None
 | r -> myCast<'T> r
```

This is also kind of "safer" and will (should?) not throw any exception, and it removes the null-stuff in F#. In C# it will return and work ok too, but None are returned as null, and if some result, well yeah it will be Some ;-)

Mind that the above code are not tested, not run in any setting or even compiled, so regard it as pseudo code. It might even have other issues...

Check also: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx
and
http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/

On the last link especially: *Matching on subtypes*

On a side note, I do not like the missing checking of entire hierachy from HttpContext to Session are non-null, but that might just be me...

**Update for some C# code using None/Some**

```
var x = GetFromSession<MyTypeInSession>(entryType, key)?.Value??defaultValue;
```

There is absolutely no need for going full arabic, reading from right to left, and from down and up with a pyramidal scheme of ifs and buts and no candy or nuts, for null-checking et al ad nauseam.

And again code is to be regarded as pseudo code...

Comment: You are absolutely right about checking the hierarchy of HttpContext to Session being non null, I've had to add that!  Regarding the Some None pattern vs the TryGet pattern, there is definitely a tradeoff here.  Overall the C# code ends up much nicer with the tryget pattern. I suppose you could do both by passing in an Option as the out parameter, it just adds some bulk on the C# side.

Comment: @jackmott :

not really... if you are using stuff like: 
    var x = GetFromSession(entryType, key)?.Value ?? defaultStuff; I cant for my bare life see how thats gonna be bad...

Comment: wasn't aware of that syntax, I'll give it a try.